# jQuery - e.stopPropagation() cancels e.preventDefault() on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I've just run into this rather annoying problem and I'm really missing some explanation as to why this behaviour is occuring - and most importantly **how to bypass it**.

I have some dynamic content which is created using jQuery on a certain event. When the content is created an `on("click")` event listener is added to the element which stops propagation of the element: `e.stopPropagation()`.

However, as the element contains anchor tags which I wish to control I would like to add a `e.preventDefault()` to the anchor tags - however it seems that `e.stopPropagation()` cancels out the `e.preventDefault()`.

The issue is recreated below:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".test-a, .test-b", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  alert("test");
});

$("body").append('<a class="test-a" href="#">Click this to see what happens when e.stopPropgation() is active (nothing)</a>');
$("body").append('<a class="test-b" href="#">Click this to see what happens when only e.preventDefault() is active</a>');

$(".test-a").on("click", function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
a{
display:block;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You probably should not be using stopPropagation in the first place. https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: @CBroe you might be right, but unfortunately the content (and the event listener with `stopPropagation`) is added from a plugin. Should maybe have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: So what exactly should work differently in the above example then?

Comment: @CBroe using `stopPropagation()` causes the `alert()` not to fire as inteded.

Comment: Hm, works as designed, I think … If you can’t talk the plugin author out of doing this in the first place, then I think at most you could try and remove those event handlers added by the plugin again. (But if those do more than just stopping propagation, you would have to re-implement “the rest” yourself again as well.)